# How to make setenv to an output of a perl script

Tags: perl, unix, setenv, aliases

I wrote a perl script that prints a path to a very specific file. I want to define a personal environment variables (by using setenv in .aliases file) that gives the output of this script.

For example, let's say that the file "myscript.pl" prints the path "/home/files/reports/file". Let's call the variable (that I want to define in .aliases file) 'myoutput'. I want that when I type "most $myoutput" in Unix, this file will be opened by most, and when I type "echo $myoutput", Unix will print the path.

How can I define a personal variable which value is determined by a script?

Comment: What shell do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `bash`, you can put the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
export myoutput=$(perl /path/to/myscript.pl)
```

For tcsh, use `.cshrc` instead, and modify the line to

```
setenv myoutput `perl /path/to/myscript.pl`
```

You need to start a new session to make the variable exist.

Comment: You can test the setenv on the commandline before you add it to .cshrc.

Comment: I added this line to ~/.cshrc and when I typed "echo $myoutput", I still got: "perl /path/to/myscript.pl"

Comment: @user3189985: Did you use the right type of quotes?

Comment: You're right. I didn't use the same type of quotes you did. I changed it now, and it works. It also worked when I put in .aliases file.

Answer (score 0):

```
myoutput=$(perl myscript.pl)
```

When your script prints more, select the correct line:

```
myoutput=$(perl myscript.pl | grep /home)
```

Comment: sorry. It didn't help. When I typed "echo $myoutput", I got: "perl myscript.pl"

Comment: I was already tyoing my answer when you specified tcsh. I wanted to give the setenv statement @choroba wrote.